# Reactive Extensions (Rx) in Scala - execute a method after a given interval

Tags: scala, reactive-programming, rx-java, rx-scala

Since I'm quite new to Reactive Extensions, I was curious about the following things.

By using Rx in Scala, I want to be able to call a method that retrieves content from an API every second.

So far, I've taken a look at the creational operators used within Rx such as Interval, Timer and so forth. But unfortunately, I cannot come up with the correct solution.

Does anyone have some experience with this, and preferably code examples to share?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Using RxJava:

```
Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
          .map(interval -> getSuffFromApi()) //Upto here, we have an observable the spits out the data from the API every second
          .subscribe(response-> System.out.println(response)); //Now we just subscribe to it
```

Or:

```
Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS) //Emit every second
          .subscribe(interval ->System.out.println(getSuffFromApi())) //onNext - get the data from the API and print it
```

Comment: Although this is a valid solution, the problem that I keep bouncing at is that the control flow terminates the execution even before the response arrives. Any suggestions?

Comment: @dsafa that means that you're doing something asynchronously and not waiting for the response. My answer assumes that `getSuffFromApi()` is a blocking call and that you don't need to execute it on a different thread. Are you doing something in a different thread? Perhaps you have a `subscribeOn` / `observeOn` somewhere?